# Deserialize django json data dump one record at the time?

Tags: django, json, deserialization

I`m trying to read a file with json-data, use the loads(data) simplejson method and extract create a dictionary representing the values for each column in a record, instead of using the "standard" or documented way of :

```
for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
    # do something with obj
```

because I want to avoid creating django orm objects for each record, I just want a dictionary representing each object so I can insert that into the database using plain SQL for gain speed. The problem is that loads(data) needs to read all the data into memory and I want to avoid that to keep memory usage low and read entry for entry in the json-data. Is it possible to get an iterator that yields data for one record? And secondly, can I skip the entire creation of django orm objects when deserializing the json data and just get a dictionary of the values?

Input and thoughts are welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create the ORM objects, there's no point in using the Django deserialization methods. Simply load the JSON using the underlying `simplejson` library:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
my_data = simplejson.loads(data)
```

Comment: but won`t that load the entire json object into memory? I`m looking for a way to avoid that. Thanks for your input anyway :-)

Comment: Why is that an issue? You're just creating a dictionary, which is fairly low-impact compared to actually creating Django model instances. In any case, I'm not aware of any way to deserialize a JSON object iteratively.